# Nodejs - NPM Unable to install Angular CLI

Tags: angularjs, node.js, command-line-interface

I want to install the Angular 2 CLI on Windows (win7 & win 10). I tried using first the Node 7.3.0 ("node-v7.3.0-x64.msi"), then also tried "node-v6.9.2-x64.msi". In steps, I did:

- Open CMD run as administrator
- traverse to "C:\program files\nodejs" directory,
- executed "npm install -g angular-cli@latest"

I get the following warning:

```
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
C:\Users\rlin\AppData\Roaming\npm\ng -> C:\Users\rlin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\angular-cli\bin\ng
C:\Users\rlin\AppData\Roaming\npm
`-- angular-cli@1.0.0-beta.24
  +-- @angular-cli/ast-tools@1.0.11
  | `-- rxjs@5.0.2
  +-- autoprefixer@6.6.0
  | `-- browserslist@1.5.1
  +-- css-loader@0.23.1
  | `-- cssnano@3.9.1
  |   `-- postcss-reduce-initial@1.0.1
  +-- html-webpack-plugin@2.24.1
  | `-- bluebird@3.4.7
  `-- tslint@4.2.0

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\angular-cli\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.0.15: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
```

Comment: Mind sharing what happens when you try to use the Angular 2 CLI?